# How to add <list> class from data row with non define property name?

Tags: c#, list, class, properties

My english is poor.

I want to add class to list class but i don't want to define property name.

Ex.
// Declare Class

```
public class LSale
{
   public int id {get;set;}
   public string name {get;set}
}
```

// Old Code

```
public DataTable dt = new DataTable();
public List<LSale> mLSale {get; set;}

foreach ( DataRow t in dt.Rows)
{
    mLSale.Add( new LSale { 
            id = Convert.ToInt32(t["id"].ToString()) , 
            name = = t["name"].ToString() });        
}
```

How to add LSale with not define id and name field
but find from property or field in LSale Class.

Example ( this code not right )

```
Type mType = typeof( LSale );    
LSale mSale = nil;
foreach ( DataRow t in dt.Rows )
{
   foreach( Propertyinfo mp in mType.GetProperties() )
   {
       mSale[mp].Value = t[mp].Value;

   }
   mLSale.Add( new mSale );
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: Its unclear what you are trying to do? are you trying to add a `LSale` instance to your list without needing to define the id and name? if so its just `new LSale()` (assuming you have a parameterless constructor)

Comment: I don't want to add or edit element in other class. I want to define new element in class and DB table. This method make sure I don't forget to assign value to element.

Comment: Yes I don't want to define id , name and other. But I will declare in LSale class and declare field in SQL Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use reflection

```
public T MapObjects<T, Y>(Y item)
        {
            T _item = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(Y).GetProperties())
            {

                if (typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public) != null)
                    typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).SetValue(_item, propValue);
            }

            return _item;
        }
```

where T is destination type and Y is source type, there's one condition here, property names of source and destination types must be the same.